# Mobile number validation for webforms

Tags: webforms

I am looking for a way to easily implement an Integer field with webforms that can do mobile number validation (US numbers only). I am aware of http://drupal.org/project/webform_validation that can do numeric validation but looking for a more direct solution. If its a hook, that works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a hook_form_alter of your form, and add your own validation to it.

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'NAME_OF_FORM') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'YOURMODULE_VALIDATE_FUNCTION';
  }
}

function YOURMODULE_VALIDATE_FUNCTION( $form, &$form_state ) {
  $mobile = $form_state['input']['field_MOBILE']['und'][0]['value'];
  $is_valid_mobile = YOUR_AWESOME_MOBILE_VALIDATOR($mobile);
  if( !$is_valid_mobile ) {
    $error_msg = 'Mobile is invalid. Please enter a valid mobile number e.g xxx-yyy.';
    form_set_error('field_MOBILE', t($error_msg));
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I installed the webform_validation module. Would this code change in any way now since we have some additional validations we can do with that. Thanks.

Comment: When doing the hook_form_alter you are adding a validate function to the array: $form['#validate'][]
That means it will not overwrite any other validations, but also add one on top of it.

Comment: Never done a hook_form_alter hence asking. Does a hook_form_alter applies to webform as well?

Answer (score 1):

Telephone numbers are not integers. For example they begin with a zero in Germany, which is meaningless for integers but significant when dialing. A string field would be more appropriate.

You will also have to think about what quality of validation you need:

1. The number looks like a telephone number
2. The number looks like a telephone number that belongs to a cellphone
3. The number is currently assigned to a cellphone.

In all cases, the way to go is a validation function as per Danno's suggestion. For 2, you need information from the ITU and its members. For 3, sending an SMS with a validation code is probably the most effective way (although some landline phones can receive SMS).

Comment: Hmm, will add that I am looking to validate only US numbers so that might reduce a bunch of cases for validating phone numbers. Also, my concern is more about getting numbers that look like phone numbers rather than some one adding 1234567890 which is not a phone number. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

[Mobile number](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_number) module (that I wrote) supports webforms and has a component for validating mobile numbers of any country. It is based on the [libphonenumber](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php) composer library.

> Mobile Number is a field type that provides mobile number validation and verification, and can be used for two factor authentication.

Comment: @pierre.vriens why are you editing all my answers?

Comment: I wanted to help ( ie ensure your answer would not get deleted because of not respecting some basic requirements on this site) ... you seem to not like that, so I performed a rollback. Feel free to reuse anything of my prior edit if you want (no credits due ...).

Comment: Module authors that provide the exact needed solution are not allowed talk about their module?

Comment: Also I would be happy to see the site's requirements as I can't find them.

Comment: @NirYariv If you are the module maintainer, we would like it if you mention it when you recommend your own module.  Also, it helps to provide a brief overview of how the module will provide a solution rather than just a link to the module.  Thanks.

Comment: See also [How to not be a spammer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).